# Не работает MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

Установил MongoDB [по гайду на DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-ubuntu-16-04-ru). Затем сделал `pecl install mongodb` и добавил `extension=mongodb.so` в **php.ini**, но при этом я по-прежнему получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found

Код:

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $mongo = new MongoClient();
    $db = $mongo->flaut;
    $collection = $db->searches;
    $content = json_decode($data, true);
    $content['_id'] = new MongoId();
    $collection->insert($content);
    echo $content['_id'];
}
```

**UDP:** [MongoDB загружена в PHP](https://gyazo.com/c0b45967eae810d634746e597c220c65).

Comment: сделайте рестарт сервера, типа `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` или на чем у вас

Comment: @LexHobbit делал рестарт и FPM и Nginx.

Comment: а что выводит `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`?

Comment: @LexHobbit вот странная вещь этот PHP. `phpinfo()` говорит, что конфиг загружен из папки `/etc/php/7.0/fpm`, а ваша команда напротив - из `/etc/php/7.0/cli`. Кому верить?

Comment: поменяйте и там и там =)

Comment: @LexHobbit уже указал и в CLI и в FPM. Не работает. Посмотрите пост, я туда добавил картинку из `phpinfo()`. MongoDB загружен.

Comment: я понял, используйте `new MongoDB\Driver\Manager` вместо `new MongoClient`

Answer (score 0):

Видимо для того чтобы было веселее жить, есть два в принципе разных клиента к mongodb:

- [mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)
- [mongodb](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

Поставили вы второй, а использовать пытаетесь первый. Итог соответственно логичный.

Comment: Я вот что-то не смог найти ни одного туториала по установке MongoDB в PHP на сервере с Linux. Mongo что, используют только на Windows? Я что-то понять не могу.

Comment: Скорее просто не имеют проблем с установкой. `pecl install mongodb` как советует мануал или банально `apt-get install php-mongodb` в debian'ах и всего делов.

Comment: Это я и сделал. Но вот как мне его теперь использовать ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не работает ни `new MongoClient()`, ни `new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");` Что с этим всем теперь делать - непонятно.

Comment: так и спрашивайте про использование тогда, а не про установку. В мануале никакого класса `MongoDB\Client` нет. Откуда вы его взяли? Если речь про рекомендуемую в мануале к `mongodb` библиотеку MongoDB PHP library, то как же вы пропустили, что она ставится отдельно через composer, а расширение даёт только весьма низкоуровневый API?

Comment: Тогда дайте, пожалуйста, конкретную ссылку на гайд, как мне использовать MongoDB в PHP. Я вот пока ничего конкретного так и не смог найти. Везде разный код и почти нигде не указано, как её установить и начать использовать от начала и до конца. Если бы я знал, что всё будет так сложно, то поставил бы обыкновенную MySQLi.

Comment: Так и выкиньте к чертям эту хипстерскую поделку и не трогайте. А как всё-таки использовать - начните с документации. http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/

Comment: Я выбрал Mongo просто потому, что мне удобнее хранить данные в JSON и работать с ними в этом формате. Может, подскажите что-то, что тоже умеет хранить данные в JSON и не так муторно настраивается? Спасибо.